# Component not getting rendered when I trigger an external event

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, axios, components

Currently, I have this search tab and these midtabs as shown in the picture.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

There's a 'Dashboard' tab that you might not be able to see but it is the leftmost tab in the picture, the search window is covering it. When I click on the search options from the dropdown, I redirect to Dashboard tab and show data for Dashboard tab first. When I'm on the Dashboard tab already while search, the application fetches data and reloads itself properly and the new data gets updated for the Dashboard tab. However, if I'm on the Recommendations tab and I click on search, I get redirected to Dashboard tab, data gets fetched but when I then switch to Recommendations tab, even though data gets fetched for Recommendation tabs, it shows a blank area under the Recommendations tab. It's only when I go to another tab and then come back to Recommendations tab is when the data gets fetched and see the data under it. Can anyone let me know what's going wrong? This issue is for all tabs except the dashboard tab.

Actions when it works fine:

1. On Dashboard tab and then search for new HCP.
2. Gets redirected to Dashboard tab again and data gets rendered properly.

Actions when it works wrong:

1. On Recommendations tab (or literally any tab other than Dashboard) and then search for new HCP.
2. Gets redirected to Dashboard tab and data gets rendered properly for Dashboard.
3. On switching to Recommendations tab, data gets fetched but nothing gets shown. However, on going to some other tab and then coming back to Recommendations tab, data gets fetched and even rendered properly.

Just a little background info, I have a Search component which is a parent component of all these components. I'm maintaining a state inside it which handles tab clicks and based on which tab is clicked on, I render that component. Also, I'm fetching all data inside of those child components like Dashboard, Recommendations, Sales Overview, etc using componentDidMount.

Here is the code for Recommendations component:

```
   class Recommendations extends Component {

state = {
    loading: false,
    page_id: 2,
    rec_panel_data: [],
    time_period: 'month',
    starRating: 0,
    declineReason: '',
    searchName: this.props.searchName,
    error: this.props.error
}

componentDidMount() {
    console.log('Clicked on Recommendations!');
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    let page_id = this.state.page_id;
    let npi_id = parseInt(this.state.searchName[0].replace(/(^.*\[|\].*$)/g, ''));
    axios.post('/test-json', {
        page_id: page_id,
        npi_id: npi_id,
        time_period: 'month'
    })
        .then((res) => {
            const dataRequest = res.data;
            console.log('received data inside recommendations comp', res.data);
            this.setState({ rec_panel_data: res.data[212], loading: false });
            console.log('State after loading data in recommendations comp: ', this.state);
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}

   return (
        <>
            <div role="tabpanel" id="tablet-6" class="tab-pane" >
                <div class="panel-body" style={{ backgroundColor: "rgb(243,243,244)", border: "none", margin: 0 }}>
                    {
                        this.state.rec_panel_data.length === 0 || this.state.loading === true ?
                            <Loader
                                style={{ marginLeft: '450px', marginTop: '10px' }}
                                type="Circles"
                                color="#0caf8d"
                                height={50}
                                width={50}
                                radius={30}
                            />
                            :
                            this.state.error === true ?
                                <div style={{ marginLeft: '350px', marginBottom: '10px' }}>
                                    The data for this HCP is currently unavailable
                                </div>
                                :
                                this.state.loading === true ?
                                    <>
                                        <Loader
                                            style={{ marginLeft: '450px', marginTop: '10px' }}
                                            type="Circles"
                                            color="#0caf8d"
                                            height={50}
                                            width={50}
                                            radius={30}
                                        />

                                    </>
                                    :
                                    <>
                                        <div class="row" style={{ marginTop: '1%' }}>
                                            <div style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%' }} >
                                                <MaterialTable
                                                ......
                                                  />
                                    </>
                              </div>
                              </div>
                          </>
                         } 
                       </div>
                     </div>
                   </>
```

I haven't included code for parent Search component but as I mentioned, it changes the tab state to 'recommendations', 'dashboard', etc based on the click and then these component gets rendered. For example like this:

```
    {
       this.state.tab_button_clicked === 'recommendations' &&
                                    <Recommendations
                                        key={this.state.finalsearchName}
                                        searchName={this.state.finalsearchName}
                                        error={this.state.error}
                                    />
    }
```

Please let me know if I'm missing something with regards to component lifecycle.

Comment: Let me know if anyone has any questions with regards to the code or the question is unclear.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] like a codesandbox

Comment: I'm not sure how to create that since I haven't use SandBox before and also I'm fetching data using axios :(

Comment: You can put small dummy data in a variable or json file

Comment: I've added an edit where I'm showing error on opening codesandbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually a very minor problem!

Added the active class for the uppermost div inside Recommendations which solved the problem.

```
  <div role="tabpanel" id="tablet-6" class="tab-pane active" >
```